# Can't start mongos process: Address already in use

Tags: linux, debian, database, mongodb, replication

I'm working with Debian 4.9.168 and I want to configure mongoDB replica set monitoring through google cloud, and I found the best solution is through bindplane bluemedora (currect me if I wrong).

So, I deployed my mongo replica and I need to start a mongos instance. I started it with that command:

```
sudo mongos --configdb rs0/<MYFIRSTIP>:27019,<MYSECONDIP>:27019 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

and I'm getting that error:

```
2019-06-09T14:18:07.899+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0" }, sharding: { configDB: "rs0/<MYIP>:27019,35.222.135.175:27019" } }
```

2019-06-09T14:18:07.900+0000 E SHARDING [mongosMain] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2019-06-09T14:18:07.900+0000 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] shutting down with code:48

So I checked if there's a process that uses that address, and there isn't:

```
netstat -tuna | grep 2701
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.13:38586       10.128.0.14:27017       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.13:27017       10.128.0.14:56518       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.13:27017       10.128.0.14:56498       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.13:27017       10.128.0.14:56552       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.13:27017       10.128.0.14:56492       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.13:27017       10.128.0.14:56550       ESTABLISHED
```

my /etc/mongod.conf file (created automaticly through mongoDB application in Google cloud - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/mongodb):

```
    # mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/mongodb/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
#
# MongoDB 3.0.x *debian* packages set bind_ip to 127.0.0.1 by default
# Compute Engine public addresses are properly firewalled by default
# set bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 to emulate pre-2.6 behavior which eases maintenance
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

#processManagement:

#security:
  #authorization: enabled
  #keyFile: replace_me

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

I really appreciate any kind of help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're binding mongos on `0.0.0.0`:

```
--bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

And by default (from your config), it binds on port `2017`:

```
  net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Your netstat shows that there is already a process listening on `0.0.0.0:2017`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

So I suggest either you change your config, or kill your already running mongos process (seems like  that is what is using the address). Try checking with the following command:

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

Comment: mongos is not running :( 

ps aux | grep mongos
idan_ch+  2228  0.0  0.0  12780  1004 pts/0    S+   15:01   0:00 grep mongos

Comment: @IdanChau try using `netstat -tunap` (add the `-p` flag for process ID and name)

Comment: still there isn't mongos process. [my netstat -tunap output](https://imgur.com/BQADsgb)

Comment: @IdanChau what do you mean there isn't? There is. The process name is `mongod`. The first process which is listening on `0.0.0.0:27017` is `mongod`. I'll edit my answer, run `ps aux | grep mongod` and then check.

Comment: yeah mongod is running, but I'm trying to start mongos too. When I killed mongod and started mongos I got error of "can't connect to master" so I needed to start both processes, but when I try to start mongos AND mongod (but in another port) it says address already in use - no matter which port I use.